On assumptions of local projection method
It is well known that Jorda(2005) proposed the following model called local projection:
$$y_{t+h} - y_{t-1} = \beta_h shock_{t} + \gamma_h ctr_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t,h}, h = 0,1,2,\dots,H.$$
I am trying to calculate AIC for such a model. To do this, I have to calculate the likelihood function, which in turn relies on the joint distribution of $\vec{\epsilon_t} = (\epsilon_{t,0},\epsilon_{t,1},\dots,\epsilon_{t,H})$. I guess that $\vec{\epsilon_t}$ has some $H+1$-dimensional Gaussian distribution since we usually estimate this model by OLS. But I have no idea how to determine the variance-covariance matrix of the distribution.
It seems reasonable for me to calculate $Var(\epsilon_{t,h})$ by Newey-West correction (Newey, West, 1987, 1994), though I am still not very sure about that.
What bothers me most is whether it is appropiote to assume $Cov(\epsilon_{t,h}, \epsilon_{t, j}) = 0$, since there may be autocorrelations between the residuals given the time-series context. I also do not know how to calculate these possibly-existing covariances. Can anyone please help me?
Note: I know there is a R-package with which one can estimate an LP and calculate the AIC. But I prefer to realise it by myself.

Have you estimated the model? So you have residuals? Then you have vectors $\hat \epsilon_t$ is not enough to calculate variance-covariance matrix estimate based on these? For example using the formula $\frac{1}{T}\sum_t \hat \epsilon_t\hat \epsilon_t^\top$ being outer product.

@JesperHybel It seems to me that a direct calculation of variance may be flawed due to potential heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation, as is described above.

@JesperHybel For example, it will be incorrect to calculate confidential interval using the covariance matrix in your comment, one has to adjust for heteroskedasticity by Newey-West corrections or so. See Jorda (2005, 2023).

You can estimate the vector model single equation instead of as VAR. You add lags until you get rid of serial correlation. Formula for HAC s.e.s is here https://www.stata.com/manuals14/tsnewey.pdf and here is a similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390139/implement-var-model-in-r-with-hac-corrected-standard-errors. It is explained on page 166 of the paper you refer to how to calculate stds for impulse response function elements.

Cross-posted on Cross Validated here.
